# Permissions for files during magento installation

Tags: magento, permissions

Im installing magento on the server. During the installation process need to give permissions for these files

> "public_html/magento/app/etc".
>
> "public_html/magento/var".
>
> "public_html/magento/media".

I can proceed through the installation only if I give 777 permission. I know that giving 777 permission isn't a good practice. What should I do for this??. Please Help

Comment: with proper .htaccess in these folders 777 will not be an issue.

Comment: @SatishMantri Can u pls tel me, what do u mean by proper htaccess??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually isn't an issue making those directorie 777 as there should be no PHP files residing in them. If in doubt, place the following code in your .htaccess file within those folders, it will deny all PHP files from being run within those directories and sub-directories.

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Can you explain more in detail?

Comment: Those directories will do contain any executable code therefore you are generally not at risk even if it is set to 777. However if you are concerned, the .htaccess setting is there to increase security.

Comment: above .htaccess rule will work only for .php files if there is support for some other executable type then those files still will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into Magento following folders for .htaccess you will find

/var/.htaccess

Order deny,allow
Deny from all

/app/.htaccess
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

this rule will be applicable to all folders with /app

and for /media/.htaccess
Options All -Indexes

php_flag engine 0

AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI

#

### enable rewrites

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
```

#

### never rewrite for existing files

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

#

### rewrite everything else to index.php

```
RewriteRule .* ../get.php [L]
```

As these .htaccess are already there in Magento you dont need to worry.

---

Some Explanation : With 777 permission there is a probability of someone dropping some .php or other executable file.
These .htaccess rules will not allow those files to be executed so even if hacker was successful in placing an executable file it will not get executed.